# Learned vs have learned

Tags: grammar

****Situation 1:****

My friend who is still alive,he is a very good student, he often helps me with my questions.

Which sentence is correct to use when I talk to another friend about him:

> (1) I **learned** a lot from him
>
> (2) I **have learned** a lot from him

****Situation 2:****

From my past work experience. In an job interview, which sentence is correct:

> (1) From my work experience in the past, I **learned** that
> carefulness is important.
>
> (2) From my work experience in the past, I **have learned** that
> carefulness is important.

****Situation 3:****
I just done a project.
Now, a teacher ask me:

> (1) What **did** you **learn** from that project?
>
> (2) What **have** you **learned** from that project?

Comment: I would use the perfect tense for all of them (ongoing or recent activity), unless the work experience was some time ago (if you had done a different kind of work in the meantime, for example). (NB It's _I have just done a project_.)

Comment: Suppose that I have been worked for the same type of job so far.
A interviewer would ask: What (did you learn)/(have you learned) from your previous jobs?

Comment: If you _have been working in_ the same type of job until now, it's appropriate for the interviewer to ask "What have you learned from your previous jobs?".

Comment: For my situation (3) in my first post, @KateBunting tell me to use present perfect, I think that she speak British English. I wonder If American speaker use the simple past " What did you learn from that project?" in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

'I learned' is for learning that is firmly in the past, whether a long time ago or the recent past:

- I learned to play piano when I was 7.
- I learned to speak French at school.
- I learned an interesting fact yesterday.

'I have learned' is still about learning in the past but it better describes a *period* of learning - ie something you learned over time, or something that you came to learn later, perhaps after a period of ignorance over something:

- I have learned a better way to do this.
- I have learned that I was wrong.
- I have learned from my mistakes.

A comparable example might be the difference between "I went" and "I have been". "*I went to the shop*" could just refer to you taking a visit to the shop, whereas "*I have been at the shop*" better describes your entire time spent there.

Comment: Your "shop" example actually shows the difference between two possible prepositions - *going **to*** and *being **at***. The difference between *I **went to** the shop* and *I **have been to** the shop* is nothing to do with "time spent there" - it's entirely a matter of *relevance to time of utterance* with the Perfect form.

Comment: I googled and I found that these 2 version are available: “what did you learn from your previous jobs? And “what have you learned from your previous jobs? Both are correct to use here. Right?